# --ag-row-height css variable in stylesheet not overriding default rowHeight in AgGridReact

Tags: ag-grid-react

I have a custom class applied to the end of the className list (using the balham-dark theme), where I use the css variables listed in the docs to make custom styles. Without rowHeight set as a grid option, and using the css variable --ag-row-height, for instance --ag-row-height: 50px, the grid is still applying the inline style of "height: 28px" onto each row, however the content of the grid cells appears to be pushed down and cut off at the bottom.  My understanding is that --ag-row-height would override the row height.  Am I missing something?

- Added "--ag-row-height: 50px" to custom a className "ag-theme-custom-dark".
- I expected each row to have a height of 50px
- What actually happened was that each "ag-row" class div has an inline style of "transform: translateY(0px); height: 28px", and the content of "ag-cell" was pushed downwards in the cell thereby cutting off the data at the bottom